# Is storing a JWT secret as docker env variable acceptable?

Tags: account-security, jwt, storage, token, node.js

I understand how JWTs work and that with my secret anyone can issue new tokens. I control the server that my node website runs on and am considering different options for hosting the key.

1. In code - Not acceptable because my code is in a github repo
2. ENV variable - seperate secrets for dev and production while not leaking to github
3. Store in database - Seems more like 2nd option with more work, being that an on-machine attacker can find access to the db anyways

2nd option looks like the best method for a simple website (no super sensitive user info like credit cards or SSNs).

Is this a good solution?

Comment: "Is this a good solution?" depends on your needs. There isn't one answer to such questions because different systems have different security needs depending on a variety of factors. Some may be fine with ENV variables, some may need a dedicated secrets service, and some may require an HSM. Ultimately you have to decide what is good enough for *you*.

Comment: In other words, [what is your threat model](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225012/what-is-a-threat-model-and-how-do-i-make-one)?

Answer (score 1):

Use environment variables as you said, just be careful in how you actually pass the value to the variable so that it doesn't leak to logs.

For example, instead of `docker run -e SECRET=foo`, use `docker run -e SECRET=$(cat my_secret)`.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t think storing not only JWT secret but any kinds of secret like ssh keys, database passwords/username etc. in docker ENV is not ideal or recommended.

You can use [Docker Secret](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/) for these kinds of things. Though I am not sure how to implement docker secret in your use case but I have used TLS certificates, ssh keys and various credentials on docker secret and passed among the swarm and it works every time.

Comment: *Why* isn't the environment ideal or recommend? Also, Docker secrets are specific to Docker swarm, which makes this suggestion of limited value to others. In essence your answer just contains a product recommendation without further details - it is unlikely to be very useful to others on a site like this.